# cannot implement post method in angular from spring microservice

Tags: angular, spring, microservices

If you want any other file or any other details, please ask

My component name is create-booking.component

**create-booking.component.ts file**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { Product } from '../service/http-client.service';
import { HttpClientService } from '../service/http-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-booking',
  templateUrl: './create-booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-booking.component.css']
})
export class CreateBookingComponent implements OnInit {

  createBooking: Product =new Product("","","","","");//here if I write new Product() it gives //error

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService, private router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute){
   
    }

  ngOnInit(): void{//empty method
  
  }


  onSubmit(){
    this.httpClientService.save(this.createBooking).subscribe(result=> 
            this.gotoBookingList());
    this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:9003/api/fetchFlights']);
  }//my method to create booking list
  //Post method under Construction

  gotoBookingList(){
    this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:9003/api/fetchFlights']);
  }//getting routed back to booking List
```

**Create-booking.html file**

//my attributes which I am fetching from one microservice to another(from SearchandBooking to BookingandPayment) are

```
//private String bookingId;

//private String bookingDate;

//private String totalPassengers;

//private String flightName;

//private String price;


<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #nameForm="ngForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="bookingId">Id</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookingId"
      required
      [(ngModel)]="createBooking.bookingId" name="bookingId">//accessing bookingId from createbooking
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="bookingDate">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookingDate"//accessing booking data form createbooking
      [(ngModel)]="createBooking.bookingDate" name="bookingDate">//accessing booking data form createbooking
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="createBooking.price" name="price">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="flightName">flightName</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flightName"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="createBooking.flightName" name="flightName">
      </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**http-client.service.ts file**//service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, retry } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


export class Product {//attributes
  constructor(
    public  bookingId: string,
    public  bookingDate: string,
    public  totalPassengers: string,
    public  flightName: string,
    public  price: string
  ) {
  }
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'// This is a service class
})

export class HttpClientService{

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient//http
  ) { }


  //Post method under Construction
  getProducts(){
      console.log('Test Call');
      return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:9003/api/fetchFlights');
  }//this method is working fine no issues
  public save(createBooking:any){//saving data method
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:9005/api/postDataOnBooking',createBooking);
  }//this is the method I am trying to send data


  
   
}
```

// I am able to do inter microservice communication along with getting values in the angular, but not able to post data.
//data is not get posted to the back end through angular, there are problems with my methods. I think.

product.component.ts File

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientService, Product} from '../service/http-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] | undefined;

  constructor(
    private httpClientService: HttpClientService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClientService.getProducts().subscribe(
      response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),
    );
  }

  handleSuccessfulResponse(response:any) {
      this.products = response;
  }
}
```

//here is the file you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the type of the data you are passing to the backend.

```
this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:9005/api/postDataOnBooking',createBooking);
```

If this does not work, checkout the angular documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

### UPDATE

I will try to give a more clear answer:

Since you want to pass the Object `Product` using a Post request, I would recommend you to pass it as a json, since this is the most common way to do it.

First of all try to set `Product` like this:

```
export class CreateBookingComponent implements OnInit {

  createBooking = {...new Product, bookingId: "", bookingDate: "", totalPassengers: "", flightName: "", price: ""};

....
```

In the `save()` function try to declare what type the parameter should have that you receive. In your case that is `Product`.

The request can configured in many ways. This is the way that works best for me:

```
  public save(createBooking: Product){
    this.httpClient.post<Product>('http://localhost:9005/api/postDataOnBooking',createBooking, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(result => {
      console.log("The request was a success!")
      },
      () => {console.log("There was an Error")});
  }
```

I prefer this way, since I'm able to subscribe to the request and can handle errors.

Comment: where is the error???

Comment: @SatyamSingh If you mean the `Prodcut` Error I would have to see the `product.model.ts`. Check if you have set everything correct in the constructor.

Comment: I added the file product.component.ts file

Comment: cannot find the answer

Comment: Is there any error message? Please add it.

Comment: no error just null if I print console from onSubmit() method

Comment: I just updated the answer.